# semantic markup for Python's difflib.HtmlDiff

Tags: python, diff, semantics

It appears Python's `difflib.HtmlDiff`, rather than using `INS` and `DEL`, uses `SPAN` elements with custom classes:

```
python -c 'import difflib; txt1 = "lorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet".splitlines(); txt2 = "lorem foo isum\ndolor amet".splitlines(); d = difflib.HtmlDiff(); print d.make_table(txt1, txt2)'
```

Before I go about fixing this myself, has anyone looked into this already?
Is there perhaps a valid reason for not using POSH?
(Google wasn't a big help here... )

Answer (score 3):

[This script](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/diff/) by Aaron Swartz uses difflib to output `ins`/`del`.

Answer (score 2):

The python bug tracker is here: http://bugs.python.org/

There's no open bug on this issue, which I guess is because most people would not care what sort of html it is as long as it works. If it's important to you, file a bug and submit a patch.

Comment: Thanks. However, I think changing the markup now would be a problem WRT backwards compatibility...